# regarding python3.2: creating a function to determine if a user-inputted date is valid or invalid

Tags: python, python-3.2

Hello I am trying to create a basic python program that determines if a user-inputted date is valid or invalid. I am just having difficult in identifying where the problem is and have been at it for a while. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code so far.

```
def main():
#get the month day and year
(month, day, year)=eval(input("Enter month, day, and year numbers:"))
date1=str(month)+"/"+str(day)+"/"+str(year)
#determine if user inputted date is valid or invalid
def Valid (month, day, year): int(month) in range(0,12), int(day) in range(0,31), int(year) in range(0,100000)
def Verify (month, day, year):
    if (month, day, year) is Valid (month, day, year):
        print ((date1), "is a valid date.")
    else:
        print ("This is not a valid date.")

Verify (month, day, year)
```

(main)

Comment: And what was your problem exactly?

Comment: Also, please note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends using ``CapWords`` for classes, ``lowercase_with_underscores`` for functions. ``eval()`` is also generally a bad solution to any problem. I presume you have also mangled the indentation of your code, as it makes no sense at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only beginning Python so doubtless I'm not doing it correctly but, altering your code as little as possible, and leaving your lines in as comments before my suggestion:

```
#determine if user inputted date is valid or invalid 
def Valid (month, day, year):
    #int(month) in range(0,12), int(day) in range(0,31), int(year) in range(0,100000) 
    return int(month) in range(1,13) and int(day) in range(1,32) and int(year) in range(1,100000)

def Verify (month, day, year):
    #if (month, day, year) is Valid (month, day, year):
    if Valid (month, day, year):
        print ((date1), "is a valid date.")
    else:
        print ("This is not a valid date.")

#get the month day and year 
(month, day, year)=eval(input("Enter month, day, and year numbers:")) date1=str(month)+"/"+str(day)+"/"+str(year) 
Verify (month, day, year)
```

Be aware that "in range(0,12)" will return True for 0 to 11 and False for 12; you need (1,13) for the month test.
Naturally this still thinks 29th Feb 1989 and 31st April are valid. Remember that years divisible by 4 are only leap years if the century is also divisible by 4, and there was no year 0 in normal usage.